# Sliding Div from left corner to right corner animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am using this animation, which is almost working fine i.e I am **moving/sliding** Div from left corner to right corner. Now the problem is, that Div is not reaching to the Edge of right corner.

**Fiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/b6KuE/16/

I am providing my code here too:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main_container">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
   border: black 1px solid;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   background-color: red;
}  
.main_container {
   border: black 1px solid;
   width: 100%;
   height: 12px;
}
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('.container').animate({
     width: 100,
     marginLeft: 300,
     marginRight: 0,
     display: 'toggle'
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Make margin left property of the animation 100% or something like 1400px

Comment: you need to change margin-left value.
check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b6KuE/23/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is using `right` and an `absolute position`.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/b6KuE/50/)

**JS:**

```
$('.container').animate({ right: 0 }, 5000);
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width:100px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%
}
.main_container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: No idea who is down voting, even my post is down voting. Please vote up my post

Comment: This answer seens to be fair enough. Why is the answer down voted? any reason ? any issues with the answer?

Comment: This is probably the simplest and most flexible answer around here. Haters gonna hate

Comment: @Necromancer It has nothing to do with my code. IE10 gets an exception when using jQuery 1.10 on jsFiddle. Anyway updated my fiddle to jQuery 1.9.1 and it's working

Answer (score 3):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6KuE/28/). you have to define `marginLeft` according to width.

Answer (score 1):

use this code.

```
$('.container').animate({
    width: 100,
    marginLeft: $(".main_container").width()-100,
    marginRight: 0,
    display: 'toggle'
}, 5000);
```

Comment: who is down voting, even my post is down voting. Please vote up my post

Comment: @Itay There is still not perfect answer, i m waiting for the best solution, but no idea why m i getting down votes ?

Comment: this is the better answer.

Comment: Yea i guess this answer is better

Comment: @Necromancer You were telling that you had to use "dynamic" width but in this answer, you may have problems with different browsers or devices such as ipads etc.

Comment: @AloneInTheDark Yea I m still waiting for the right and reasonable answer, but i guess i have got enough down votes for no reason

Comment: il give you 2 reasons. 1.You were rude to ppl trying to answer your question. 2. If you keep asking ppl to vote you up then ppl tend to do the opposite. Dont force ppl to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I you're moving it from left to right, the width property doesn't have to change.
You need to set the margin left and position in the css properties like so:

```
$('.container').animate({
     position: 'absolute',
        marginLeft: '100%',
        marginRight: 0,
        display: 'toggle'
    }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:

```
var containerWidth = $('.main_container').width();
var marginLeft = containerWidth - 100 - 2;
$('.container').animate({
    width: 100,
    marginLeft: marginLeft,
    marginRight: 0,
    display: 'toggle'
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.container').animate({  
width: 100, 
right: 0, 
display: 'toggle'
 }, 5000);
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/b6KuE/49/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.container').animate({
        width: 100,
     marginLeft: '81.5%',
        marginRight: 0,
        display: 'toggle'
    }, 5000);
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b6KuE/48/).